# Go - Testing - No output

Tags: go

I have the following test which is working but isn't giving the "official" output when running:

```
func TestDeployLive(t *testing.T) {
// EXPECTING PASS
un, pw := GetGlobalAdminLogins()
sc, err, _ := PostImage("apps/10130/icon", un, pw, "/valid.png")
sc2, err2, _ := PostImage("apps/10130/learn-more-image", un, pw, "/valid-learn-more.png")

if err != nil && err2 != nil {
    t.Error("Fail")
} else {
    if sc != 200 || sc2 != 200 {
        t.Error("Fail")
    } else {
        deploy, err3, json := DeployApp("apps/10130/deploy", un, pw, "live")
        fmt.Print(deploy)
        if err3 != nil {
            t.Error("Fail")
        } else {
            if deploy != 200 {
                t.Error("Fail")
            } else {
                if json.Data[0].LiveDate != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Pass Live")
                    t.Logf("Success")
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("Fail Live")
                    t.Error("Fail")
                }
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

My output is:
`200`
`Pass Live`

Which as you can see means the test has passed but I am not getting the proper 
`--- FAIL: TestIconImagePost (0.76s)` for example.

Do I have to do something to get the output to display - my other tests are displaying the output correctly?

UPDATE:

If i run with -v on the end it will show it, and shows its passing. But my question is, why do all my other tests show up without the need for `-v` but this new test needs it?

Any ideas?

Comment: Rule of thumb with Go, which was co-invented by Ken Thompson, one of the heads behind UNIX: "No news are good news."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing tests aren't displayed by default. Hence the `-v` option…